# What do you call the following operations on a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, permutations, combinations

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix of the following form, where the
diagonal is always zero:

\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}

For simplicity, you can imagine that the elements above or below the
diagonal can be represented with no loss of information as a vector;
e.g., $(1,1,0,1,1,0)$ for $A$.

Given that their are four ones and
six total "slots" to arrange them, we can say there are $\left(\begin{array}{c}
6\\
4
\end{array}\right)=15$ possible symmetric matrices that can be rearranged from $A$. My
question is: what do you call the series of operations on $A$ that
generates these kinds of symmetric matrices?

Comment: I don't think it has any name, so it's up for grabs.  You could call it "apricotification" if you like ;-)

Comment: I like the sound of that